# Run-time error 91 Object variable or With Block variable not set occurs occasionally

Tags: excel, vba

When I run my script, I sometimes get the error

> Object variable or With Block variable not set

The error occurs on the line

`.Cells(7, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy`

```
Sub DailyBH()

Dim dailySht As Worksheet 'worksheet storing latest store activity
Dim recordSht As Worksheet 'worksheet to store the highest period of each day
Dim lColDaily As Integer ' Last column of data in the store activity sheet
Dim lCol As Integer ' Last column of data in the record sheet
Dim maxCustomerRng2 As Range ' Cell containing the highest number of customers
Dim maxCustomerCnt As Double ' value of highest customer count

Set dailySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("hourly KPI")
Set recordSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("@BH KPI")
With recordSht
    lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

' KMC BH
With dailySht
    lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'Row to scan
    maxCustomerCnt = Round(Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(38, 1), .Cells(38, lColDaily))), 2)
    Set maxCustomerRng2 = .Range(.Cells(38, 1), .Cells(38, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)

    Range(.Cells(1, maxCustomerRng2.Column), .Cells(2, maxCustomerRng2.Column)).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1) = DateValue(.Cells(1, maxCustomerRng2.Column))

    Range(.Cells(10, maxCustomerRng2.Column), .Cells(11, maxCustomerRng2.Column)).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(10, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(10, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    recordSht.Cells(10, lCol + 1) = DateValue(.Cells(10, maxCustomerRng2.Column))

    Range(.Cells(19, maxCustomerRng2.Column), .Cells(20, maxCustomerRng2.Column)).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(19, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(19, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    recordSht.Cells(19, lCol + 1) = DateValue(.Cells(19, maxCustomerRng2.Column))

    Range(.Cells(28, maxCustomerRng2.Column), .Cells(29, maxCustomerRng2.Column)).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(28, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(28, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    recordSht.Cells(28, lCol + 1) = DateValue(.Cells(28, maxCustomerRng2.Column))

    Range(.Cells(37, maxCustomerRng2.Column), .Cells(38, maxCustomerRng2.Column)).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(37, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(37, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    recordSht.Cells(37, lCol + 1) = DateValue(.Cells(37, maxCustomerRng2.Column))
End With


' WCR BH
With dailySht
    lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    maxCustomerCnt = Round(Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(39, 1), .Cells(39, lColDaily))), 2)
    Set maxCustomerRng2 = .Range(.Cells(39, 1), .Cells(39, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)

    .Cells(3, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(3, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(3, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(12, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(12, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(12, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(21, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(21, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(21, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(30, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(30, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(30, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(39, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(39, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(39, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With


' NRR BH
With dailySht
    lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    maxCustomerCnt = Round(Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(40, 1), .Cells(40, lColDaily))), 2)
    Set maxCustomerRng2 = .Range(.Cells(40, 1), .Cells(40, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)

    .Cells(4, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(4, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(4, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(13, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(13, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(13, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(22, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(22, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(22, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(31, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(31, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(31, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(40, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(40, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(40, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With


' LRR BH
With dailySht
    lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    maxCustomerCnt = Round(Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(41, 1), .Cells(41, lColDaily))), 2)
    Set maxCustomerRng2 = .Range(.Cells(41, 1), .Cells(41, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)

    .Cells(5, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(5, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(5, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(14, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(14, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(14, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(23, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(23, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(23, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(32, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(32, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(32, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(41, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(41, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(41, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With


' CRR BH
With dailySht
    lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    maxCustomerCnt = Round(Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(42, 1), .Cells(42, lColDaily))), 2)
    Set maxCustomerRng2 = .Range(.Cells(42, 1), .Cells(42, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)

    .Cells(6, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(6, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(6, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(15, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(15, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(15, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(24, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(24, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(24, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(33, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(33, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(33, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(42, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(42, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(42, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With


' Network BH
With dailySht
    lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    maxCustomerCnt = Round(Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(44, 1), .Cells(44, lColDaily))), 2)
    Set maxCustomerRng2 = .Range(.Cells(44, 1), .Cells(44, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)

    .Cells(8, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(8, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(8, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(17, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(17, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(17, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(26, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(26, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(26, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(35, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(35, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(35, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(44, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(44, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(44, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With

' URR BH
With dailySht
    lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    maxCustomerCnt = Round(Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(43, 1), .Cells(43, lColDaily))), 2)
    Set maxCustomerRng2 = .Range(.Cells(43, 1), .Cells(43, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)

    .Cells(7, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(7, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(7, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(16, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(16, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(16, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(25, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(25, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(25, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(34, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(34, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(34, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    .Cells(43, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
    recordSht.Cells(43, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    recordSht.Cells(43, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With

Set maxCustomerRng = Nothing
Set dailySht = Nothing
Set recordSht = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `maxCustomerRng2` Is `Not Nothing`, in case `Find` fails.

So you need to trap this type of error, using something like the code below:

```
Set maxCustomerRng2 = .Range(.Cells(38, 1), .Cells(38, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not maxCustomerRng2 Is Nothing Then  ' <-- added this line
    ' rest of your code goes here
```